# MySQL: Group by two columns without regard to order

Tags: mysql

I have a table, like text messages, which has `from`, `to`, `message` and `time` columns (among others).  I'm trying to ask for the most recent record between two numbers (`from` and `to`) *without regard to direction*.

Here is an example of the table:

```
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+
| from         | to              | message            | time         |
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 555-1234     | 555-9876        | I'll be there.     | 06:00        |
| 555-9876     | 555-5555        | message3           | 05:30        |
| 555-9876     | 555-1234        | Bring beer         | 05:00        |
| 555-9876     | 555-1234        | My place at 8pm    | 04:00        |
| 555-9876     | 555-5555        | message2           | 03:45        |
| 555-5555     | 555-9876        | message1           | 03:30        |
| 555-9876     | 555-1234        | Are you coming?    | 03:00        |
| 555-1234     | 555-9876        | Yeah, what's up?   | 02:00        |
| 555-9876     | 555-1234        | Are you there?     | 01:00        |
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

I want to get just the following records from this example:

```
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+
| from         | to              | message            | time         |
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 555-1234     | 555-9876        | I'll be there.     | 06:00        |
| 555-9876     | 555-5555        | message3           | 05:30        |
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

How do I ask for these?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT LEAST(`from`, `to`) AS `from`,
           GREATEST(`from`, `to`) AS `to`,
           MAX(`time`) AS `max_time`
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY LEAST(`from`, `to`),
             GREATEST(`from`, `to`)
) t2
    ON LEAST(t1.`from`, t1.`to`)    = t2.`from` AND
       GREATEST(t1.`from`, t1.`to`) = t2.`to`   AND
       t1.`time` = t2.`max_time`
```

By the way, what is the reason for naming your column `from`, which is a MySQL keyword?  Please use another name.

Comment: Wouldn't an inner join only return conversations with records in BOTH directions?  I realize that the example I gave only has these, but the use case doesn't necessarily.  Also: I used `from` instead of using my REAL code, which is actually 2 tables, one which appears twice, to simplify the example.  I figured better to solicit an easier question and force valid answers to use the escape character (`) than to dumb down a use case.

Comment: @Bing No, the `INNER JOIN` has nothing to do with that.  I would advise you to try my query and then give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You coynd use a subquery with max and tuple

```
select * from my_table 
where (from, to, time) in ( select from, to, max(time) 
                            from my_table
                            group by from, to)
```

Comment: This also might have a problem because it will treat `from, to` as being different than `to, from` for the same pair of values.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  thanks  .. i know  .. but  my is primarly a suggestion for how obtain these value using tuple , subquery and group by .. ( i don't know the  real need of OP)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from messages m1
where time = greatest((
    select max(time)
    from messages m2
    where m2.from = m1.from
      and m2.to   = m1.to
),(
    select max(time)
    from messages m2
    where m2.from = m1.to
      and m2.to   = m1.from
))
```

http://rextester.com/RDTZAK70241